# Cannot update profile for Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, profile-page

When I try to save my profile on Stack Overflow with or without any changes, I always get this error message. I did create my profile just recently and I can try to upload new image to fix image error, but I am clueless about the username change, since the username is the same as before.

I am using Google Chrome on OS X 10.11.4 with no extensions (incognito mode). I get the same error in Safari.

Screenshots:
[image: Error message][image: Profile page with no change][image: Profile name history]

Comment: You changes your display name from your real(?) name to Spiso on the 17th, you can't change in back yet.

Comment: As far as I am aware, I never changed my display name. All I did was to register myself and start using the site, that is why this is so confusing. Also that means Stackoverflow is prefilling this form with my old display name instead of the new one...

Comment: *I never changed my display name...my old display name instead of the new one.* This is very confusing. How can there be an "old" display name if you never changed it?

Comment: Ok, explain this: Now I removed my profile picture and wrote Spiso into display name + entered my bio and was able to save it. Suddenly my display name here changed to Jozef Spisiak and the form is the same (showing display name Jozef Spisiak per default). However in my profile page next to the menu I still have display name Spiso. Also I cannot save my profile again unless I write Spiso into display name...

Comment: Your browser (or plugin) is probably pre-filling the fields.

Comment: You look like [Josh Groban](http://cdn.inquisitr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Kimmel-Centers-Hit-Back-After-Josh-Groban-Comments-About-Price-Gouging.jpg)

Comment: @Rob Opened in Safari, where I don't have any extensions installed and never logged into stackoverflow before. Same as with Chrome in inkognito. Anyway, I think we should close this ticket, since it is no longer correct. I can update my profile now properly, it is just I have to write my display name as Spiso and after I save it it changes to Jozef Spisiak everywhere and later changes back to Spiso (or if I try to save it and it fails validation, it changes to Spiso again).

Answer (score 2):

I can save my profile after removing the picture and selecting it again and writing Spiso as Display name every time I want to do a change in my profile (is prefilled with Jozef Spisiak).

Regarding why do I need to do that, I will open a different ticket with better description of this problem.